# Radio button response very slow

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-volley, android-viewholder, android-radiobutton

I have a recyclerView with text and radio button like this:

[image]

When I select any of radio button it get a id.
My problem is when I select a radio button it response very slow(i.e. the red color on radio button appears 2-3 sec later after click on radio button).

Here is code of my adapter class form where I handle radio button click listener

```
public class BusinessTypeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BusinessTypeAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<BusinessTypeModel> moviesList;
    private int lastSelectedPosition = -1;
    private Context context;
    private OnItemClick mCallback;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView title,id;
        RadioButton radioButton;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.businessname);
            id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);
            radioButton = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.select);
//
//            radioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//                @Override
//                public void onClick(View v) {
//                    final BusinessTypeModel movie = new BusinessTypeModel();
////                    boolean isChecked = radioButton.isChecked();
////                    if (isChecked) {
////                        String clickValue = movie.getId();
//
////                        Log.d("list", moviesList.toString());
//
//                    lastSelectedPosition = getAdapterPosition();
//                    notifyDataSetChanged();
////                        Toast.makeText(BusinessTypeAdapter.this.context,
////                                "selected offer is " + clickValue,
////                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                }
//
////                }
//            });

        }
    }


    public BusinessTypeAdapter(List<BusinessTypeModel> moviesList,Context ctx,OnItemClick listener) {
        this.moviesList = moviesList;
        context = ctx;
        this.mCallback = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.businestypelistitem, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final BusinessTypeModel movie = moviesList.get(position);
        holder.title.setText(movie.getTitle());
        holder.id.setText(movie.getId());

        holder.radioButton.setChecked(lastSelectedPosition == position);
        boolean isChecked = holder.radioButton.isChecked();
        if(isChecked) {
            String clickValue = movie.getId();
            mCallback.onClick(clickValue);
            Toast.makeText(BusinessTypeAdapter.this.context,
                    "selected offer is holder " + clickValue,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return moviesList.size();
    }

    public interface OnItemClick {
        void onClick (String value);
    }
}
```

How to resolve this issue.

If any one want to know more info please let me know.

Comment: Why are you using a single `RadioButton` and not a `RadioButtonGroup`?

Comment: (because number of radio buttons not decide)actually radio buttons generate as a list-Item dynamically in recyclerView@hamena314.

Comment: You dont need to know the number of `RadioButtons` beforehand in order to use a `RadioButtonGroup`. But here is an example of using only a single `RadioButton` in a layout: http://www.zoftino.com/android-recyclerview-radiobutton

Comment: my code inspired by same link you mentioned ..it's working .. my issue is slow response of radio button.. @hamena314

Comment: @Neo your binding is not efficient, you can do one thing, declare a boolean variable in your BusinessTypeModel and name it checked, and on click simply make that boolean true, and while populating if it is already true set radio button as checked

Comment: it is slow because view is taking time to rerender

Comment: how to resolve this slow rendering issue @Ashwani

Comment: try using notifyDataChangedAt(position), it will not rerender the whole UI it will re render only element at that position, by default it is rendering all your components again and hence the lag is ther